# Brew services start and stop issue

Tags: macos, service, homebrew, launchctl

I've got two services one is elasticsearch, the other is mongodb, recently I found the mongodb service have some issues while i start or stop it.

The case is while I start mongo with the following command when the mongodb service is actually stopped.
`brew services start mongodb`,
it shows me following errorCode but it was started
----------Error Code-------------
/Users/attis/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist: service already loaded
Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/501 /Users/attis/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist` exited with 133.

while I stop mongo with the following command when the mongodb service is actually started. it shows me the following errorCode but it was stopped after it.
---------Error Code---------------
Error: Service `mongodb` is not started.

I'm not familliar with the launchctl mechanism. Could any one suggest to help me fix the annoying issue. especially while i start all services it will block all the following services that start after mongodb from getting started.

[image: when started the picture also suggest with yellow warning]

Comment: Did you ever fix this?

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same issue with RabbitMQ and the fix was intuitive - simply unload the plist manually. Not sure if it will fix Mongodb but worth a shot. In my case I did:

```
$ brew services start rabbitmq
/Users/XXXX/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.rabbitmq.plist: service already loaded
Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/502 /Users/XXXX/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.rabbitmq.plist` exited with 37.

$ launchctl unload /Users/XXXX/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.rabbitmq.plist
$ brew services start rabbitmq
==> Successfully started `rabbitmq` (label: homebrew.mxcl.rabbitmq)
```

Comment: Yes `launchctl unload blah.plist` seems to have fixed my problems with `brew services stop tor` and `brew services restart postgresql@14`

Answer (score 0):

I had a brew service start issue with my rabbitmq in the following.

```
Try re-running the command as root for richer errors.
Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/501 /Users/USERNAME/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.rabbitmq.plist` exited with 5.
```

fixed:

```
launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.rabbitmq.plist
```